# How to access a specific column and also random simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Accessing column in pandas.

How to access a single column and multiple random columns in pandas data frame?.
if I have 6 columns ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] how can I access column 'a' and the remaining 3 are random. I try using `df.sample()` but it will show random column and column 'a' not automatically show.

Comment: `np.random.choice(df.columns[1:], 3, False)` so a full example would be `df[['a']+list(np.random.choice(df.columns[1:], 3, False))]`

Comment: and how to show the content?

Answer (score 2):

Use `set_index` with `sample`:

```
>>> df.set_index('a').sample(3, axis=1).reset_index()
    a   d   e   b
0   1   4   5   2
1   7  10  11   8
2  13  16  17  14
3  19  22  23  20
4  25  28  29  26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
random_cols = np.random.choice(df.columns[1:], (3,), replace=False)\
                .tolist()

df[['a'] + random_cols]
```